# Flutter: How to await currentUrl() from WebViewController in FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-provider

### What I try to do

I implemented a webview and want to show the current url on another page using provider.
So `onWebViewCreated` I try to set the `controller` value via `setController` and consume it in the `Consumer` widget together with a `FutureBuilder` and an if statement. If `hasData` is truthy, I want to access the `controller` e.g. to get the `currentUrl()`.

### Where I'm stuck

The `Text` with `controller.data?.currentUrl()` returns `Instance of 'Future<String?>'`. I know I need to `await` it, but I don't know how.

#### Code

`profile.page.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:quirion_flutter/providers/router.providers.dart';
import 'package:quirion_flutter/widgets/webview.widgets.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<WebviewRouter>(builder: ((context, value, child) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: [
          const BankingWebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://banking-dev.quirion.de/setup/personal-data',
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: value.controller.future,
              builder: ((BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                if (controller.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('${controller.data?.currentUrl()}'),
                      Text(value.route),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return const SafeArea(child: Text('Nothing here'));
              })),
        ]),
      );
    }));
  }
}
```

#### References

- https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2
- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#11
- https://discord.com/channels/420324994703163402/421445316617961502/1039197342231973898

Answer (score 0):

I went with a probably fairly simply solution. I just used another `FutureBuilder` which `future` then is `controller.data?.currentUrl()` (we remember, it returned `Instance of Future<String?>`) and then the `snapshot` to access the resolved data. Worked for me. Though, if there are better solution, I'm still happy for additional answers.

```dart
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<WebviewRouter>(builder: ((context, value, child) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: [
          const BankingWebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://my-url.com',
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: value.controller.future,
              builder: ((BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                if (controller.hasData) {
                  // SOLUTION START
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: controller.data?.currentUrl(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.data}');
                        }
                        return const SafeArea(child: Text('Loading...'));
                      });
                  // SOLUTION END
                }
                return Container();
              })),
        ]),
      );
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's actually perfectly valid to use nested `FutureBuilder`s when you've got multiple `Future`s to tackle. (There *is* also a solution in form of chaining your `Future`s, then passing the return value(s) down, maybe in the form of a data structure. But it's likely overkill in your case.)